# Refresh a page after getting info from server after submiting(react)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to refresh a page after submitting info to the server and getting a response (using the submit button).
Any idea how to implement it in my handleSubmit function?

here's the function:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
 event.preventDefault();
 setSubmitting(true);

 setTimeout(() => {
   setSubmitting(false);
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: Do you mean hard reloading the page? and why you need this behavior?

Comment: I think so, the page stays the same (written pending) also after the submittion of info, and I think a refresh is needed

Comment: Just to notify, hard reloading will re-initialize all your states, even if you have a store, it will also re-initialize to the initial state.

Comment: oh that's not what I'm looking for, I want to initialize only the data given by the server (in order to write it down in the page)